# Correct way to find this (shellshock patch) package?

Tags: bash, debian, package-management, shellshock

I was out to patch some squeeze servers for the shellshock bug.

A few googles later I found that I could [updated my apt sources list](http://jamesmcfadden.co.uk/patching-the-bash-shellshock-bug-debian-6-squeeze/). This did however not work for some reason.

I tried to search for the package at packages.debian.org without luck. It took me a good while to find [this post](http://tipstricks.itmatrix.eu/?p=2342), which was the solution to my problems.

My question is, how can I find these packages directly, without finding a blog post about them? Am I just looking at the wrong place at packages.debian.org? I tried listing all squeeze and squeeze-updates packages, and I only found non-patched bash packages.

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of fixing the bash package

```
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get install bash
```

To find out if it's not patched, run this command and see if you get output **SHELLSHOCK ENABLED**

```
env x='() { :;}; echo SHELLSHOCK ENABLED' bash -c "echo Hello Big Boy"
```

You did not mention which version of Debian you are using, here's an example link. You need to download the right bash deb package and install it

http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/bash/

Comment: Did you read my question? I don't think you really answered it, but the apt-get clean might explain why it did not help to update my sources.

Comment: Updated the answer. Sorry, I overlooked

Comment: OK, so I guess I would just have to bookmark http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main then? :)

Comment: Yeah. They have mirrors in other countries, so maybe you can remove *us* and try the 2 letter domain name of a country close to you: http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian/pool/main/

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Debian squeeze isn't *exactly* out of support, as the LTS project tries to bring long term support to Debian: https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using

#### Searching for packages

- either on packages.debian.org or
- by using `aptitude search pkg-name` or
- by using `apt-cache search pkg-name`

#### Searching for files

- either on packages.debian.org or
- by using `apt-file search pkg-name`